# Creating a bag that will have different textures on each side

Tags: modeling

I'm attempting to model this bag in Blender:

[image]

I'm planning to export this as an .obj file and use it in 3JS. In 3JS I need to be-able to place a different material with/without a texture on every side - both outside and inside.

I have a model that I was using which allowed me to do this but I've ran into some problems with it and I think it would be overly complicated, for me, to try to fix it. 
It allowed me to do the above by treating each side as an individual mesh that I can refer to in the 3JS world via an array index and place whatever I want on it.

How could I do the same with a mesh built from the ground up? And how do I draw the sides in?

Here's what I have so far:

[image]

And the actual Blender object:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate?: (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: I disagree @NickBosse as I'm trying to do the different materials in 3JS - unless this is the exact same process then it isn't a duplicate

Comment: I think this is more question about three.js than Blender itself.

Comment: @LukeD I think that could be argued yes - but in order to get the effect I needed in 3JS I needed to use Blender to set each side as an individual mesh