# Wanting to make a paper shopping bag

Tags: modeling

I'm wanting to make a paper shopping bag like the bags you'd get at the apple store or Chanel. I've been trying to follow a tutorial on youtube and I've got the first steps down making a loop. But the next step the tutorial is saying to select the edges and connect them, so it makes an concave indent that you see on the sides of bags (included photo below). But I'm not able to make these selections. How would I go about doing this in Blender 2.8 because I've played around with almost every setting and it just keeps making indents or extruded edges. [image]

Comment: hard to understand, could you show some screenshots of the wireframe and what can't you achieve?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102144/how-to-make-walls-with-the-same-thickness https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95447/creating-a-bag-that-will-have-different-textures-on-each-side